# Is there any information on whether (and/or when) Flixbus will come to the Midwest?

Tags: usa, public-transport, buses, flixbus

Flixbus started operating on the West Coast last year, and a week ago [it began operation on the East Coast](https://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/news/2019/05/29/flixbus-launches-east-coast-4-99-seats-new-york-city-washington-dc/1262417001/). I was wondering if there is some information, official or not, on whether it is planning to enter the Midwest, and if so, then when? I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: For those voting to close as "primarily opinion-based," this is asking if there is any information (i.e. not opinions) on the subject. If there is no public information (and I suspect there isn't, as a new operation may want some time to focus on their new routes before considering expansion), that's an answer.

Comment: And how would you prove a negative? Maybe one of their employees left a hint in a Facebook comment...

Comment: @chx by adding another answer? You could even make a CW answer listing relevant sources that haven't mentioned it (to the best of your searching).

Comment: Just curious, why are you interested in FlixBus' plans considering there are the dozens of intercity bus companies already operating in the midwest already?

Comment: @Carl Flixbus is much cheaper.

Comment: @user77409 more competition helps for sure but they're definitely not always cheaper: e.g. for DC-NY July 4th we've got 6 cheaper bus companies on Busbud. (Disclosure: Busbud is my day job.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a publicly announced plan for expansion I'd expect to find it in Flixbus's [press releases](https://global.flixbus.com/company/press-room/press-releases), but there's nothing there. There's also nothing there about the services recently started on the East Coast, so it might not be the most reliable source.

If there are announcements on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/FlixBus) I couldn't find them amongst the noise. There's a reference on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/FlixBus) to the article referred to by the OP, but I didn't see anything else relevant. There might be references in the newsletter they say they send out, but I didn't find an archive to check.

So, nothing in the obvious official sources. Anything unofficial can be ignored by the company if it doesn't suit them.

Answer (score 2):

FlixBus announced their Texas and New York expansions in [this Press Release last December](https://cdn.flixbus.de/2018-12/FlixBus_NewYorkAnnoucement_Oct2018_final.pdf?_sp=ab3b22a9-850c-422f-adc2-8a8b22223585.1559869344914&atb_pdid=254a384b-bdcd-4ddc-9de3-6d39950f012f&wt_eid=2155304518685247339&wt_t=1559869344923). Texas started very soon after it was announced, much sooner than New York which started almost half a year later. They can move quite fast to start routes when the right opportunity presents itself.

So far they haven't announced it publicly, nor do they have any [jobs posted](https://flix.careers/) that would hint at such an expansion.